# When inline editing the id parameter is not included in the POST data with jqGrid (5.1.1)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a configuration that includes action buttons in each row:
[image: jqgrid row with action buttons]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'path_url?action=ajax.load',
                editurl: 'path_url',
                datatype: "json",
                colModel: [ {
                        label: 'Actions',
                        width: '10em',
                        formatter: 'actions',
                        editable: false,
                        sortable: false
                }, {
                        label: 'Network',
                        name: 'network',
                        width: '20em',
                        key: true,
                        editable: true,
                        editrules : { required: true}
                }, {
                        ...
                }, {
                        label: 'Comment',
                        name: 'comment',
                        editable: true,
                        sortable: false
                } ],
                autowidth: true,
                gridview: true,
                prmNames: { oper: "action",
                        editoper: "ajax.update",
                         addoper: "ajax.add",
                         deloper: "ajax.delete"
                },
                sortname: 'network',
                sortorder : 'asc',
                viewrecords: true,
                height: 'auto',
                rowNum: 10000,
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });
        ...
```

when the delete button is clicked the POST data includes "**id**=*value*" of the record to delete:

```
vars {
  action        = 'ajax.delete'
  id            = '129.186.0.0'
}
```

When the edit button is used to edit a row, when the save button is used, the POST data does not include it, I get only the new values:

```
vars {
  action        = 'ajax.update'
  comment       = 'note goes here'
  netmask       = '255.255.0.0'
  nettype       = '1'
  network       = '1.4.0.0'
}

  id            = '192.188.159.0'    /* missing! the old value of the key field */
```

I was able to hack the source to "fix" this (at line 12206) in `saveRow()`:

```
if(tmp) {
    tmp[opers.oper] = opers.editoper;
    tmp[opers.id] = oldRowId;               /* added, --john */
    if (tmp[idname] === undefined || tmp[idname]==="") {
        ...
```

but surely there is a **proper** way to fix this which has eluded me?

*FWIW, the id field gets included when using the edit and delete buttons on the bottom of the grid:*
[image: jqgrid bottom buttons]

Comment: It's very bad to allow to edit the id value (`network` in your case). Moreover you don't specified mandotory `name` property for the first column (`Actions`). I develop alternative [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork to commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which you use, and can't specific features of Guriddo. I would recommend you to try to **remove** `key: true` option and try **to add** `jsonReader: { id: "network" }` option of jqGrid. jqGrid will get the `id` parameter during editing from `id` attribute of the row.

Comment: Thanks, the missing id was indeed the problem.

Comment: You are welcome! You don't need to include `id` property with **the same** value as already existing property `network`. jqGrid *have to* assign `id` attribute to every row of the grid (to `<tr>` elements) known as rowids. By default jqGrid assign `id` attribute from `id` property of input data, but `jsonReader: { id: "network" }` option inform to get the information from another property. `id` attribute will be not changed during editing and you should solve the problem. It's important that you reload the data after editing to have sync between `id` and network (in `aftersavefunc` callback).

Comment: The best would be to change the format of input data and to use *immutable* id of the data.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification.  In my case, the network is the id/key, but I understand they could be different.

Comment: Try to edit the row and then edit the same row once more. Which `id` will be sent to the server: the result of the first editing or the original id value, which would be wrong value now?

Comment: I'm recreating the grid after every edit, so I don't think that case will arise.  Right?

Comment: It would be a workaround. In general it's enough to reload the grid data by call of `$("#jqGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Oleg's comment, here is the answer:

My data source did not include an ***id*** field:

```
"rows": [
    {"network": "1.2.0.0", "netmask": "255.255.0.0", "nettype": "1", "comment": "huh" },
    ...
]
```

There are two fixes.  One is to include the `jsonReader: { id: "network" }` option as suggested, which will synthesize the id.  The other is to fix the data source to include the id:

```
"rows": [
    {"id": "1.2.0.0", "network": "1.2.0.0", "netmask": "255.255.0.0", "nettype": "1", "comment": "huh" },
    ...
]
```

in both cases, the `key: true` option is no longer needed.

**[Edit]** Note: having an immutable ***id*** is a good thing, *(rather than one which shadows an editable field)* -- just not a thing which is available to me in this particular case.